# What happens in CSS when lists are nested in paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to understand the strange rendered browser output when I try to nest lists (`<ul>` or `<ol>`) in paragraphs (`<p>`).
It seems as if CSS exits the scope of the outer paragraph as soon as the list occurs.
And it also seems independent from the browser and appears in e.g. in Firefox and Vivaldi alike.
I have problems to design my style sheet because the behavior is so unexpected and beyond my understanding and reasoning.
Maybe, I can best explain it with the following example HTML code.

```html
<p style="background-color:red">
  First line.
  <ul style=background-color:yellow>
    <li> Item one </li>
    <li> Item two </li>
  </ul>
  Last line.
</p>
```

This is how it looks like in the browser:

[image: snapshot]

I would expect that there is a yellow block inside a red block.
But instead, entering the list seems to leave the outer scope.
And the "Last line." is neither red nor yellow.

Can anybody point me to the inner logic of this behavior?

Comment: Check how your browser renders HTML. `<p>` can not contain `<ul>`/`<ol>`, so it is rendered as two different elements, not nested

Answer (score 1):

[Paragraphs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) can only have [**phrasing content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content).

`p` is an element that doesn't require an explicit closing tag. As such, ***the tag is automatically closed once the browser hits a non-phrasing content element*** - such as your `ul`.

So your browser actually renders your intended

```html
<p style="background-color:red">
  First line.
  <ul style=background-color:yellow>
    <li> Item one </li>
    <li> Item two </li>
  </ul>
  Last line.
</p>
```

as

```html
<p style="background-color:red">
  First line.</p>
<ul style=background-color:yellow>
  <li> Item one </li>
  <li> Item two </li>
</ul>
Last line.
<p></p>
```

If you need to wrap your list in another element, use a `div`, a `section`, `article` or whatever most closely meets the semantics of your content at that point.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that would explain the behavior. Maybe I need to do a deep study of the link you added, I am not familiar with the concept of "phrasing content". I appreciate that you took the time and I don't want to urge you to do my homework. But can you give me a little hint what it means. And maybe, if there is a way to still get the behavior I expect?

Comment: I'm neither, but I am aware that `p` elements are not suited to host other block-level elements. Read the last sentence in my answer for your additional question.

Comment: No, so it seems. Thank you, I guess I'll make some time to study you link. And I probably have to learn to live with the quirks.

Comment: No quirk here, that's just how it works. You need to adjust your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Nested block-level elements like `<ul>` inside `<p>` can lead to unpredictable rendering due to HTML specifications; consider using `<div>` elements for desired styling.

Comment: I am working on a book in HTML that shall alsol be converted into other formats. Changing all the tag names destroys everything: the logic of the text and my ability to write a style sheet. And then, I still don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Nothing about that is unpredictable; it behaves exactly as must be expected.

Comment: I am not saying that the browser misbehave, I ask the question because I don't understand what's going on. ... But thank's for you answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` for that purpose instead of the `p` tag:

```html
<div style="background-color:red">
  First line.
  <ul style=background-color:yellow>
    <li> Item one </li>
    <li> Item two </li>
  </ul>
  Last line.
</div>
```